# java - execute a command in linux

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet running in tomcat6. I use the following code to execute a command in
ubuntu 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/wine cmd /c some.vbs");
the problem is tomcat6 runs the programme as "tomcat6" user, the
above java command. So the the above commands getErrorStream returns as
"wine: /home/randeel/.wine is not owned by you"
I have installed "wine" using user "randeel".
Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you,
Rana.

Comment: If you do "chmod a+rwx /home/randeel/.wine" it works ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: You must switch the user. Try

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo -U randeel /usr/bin/wine cmd /c some.vbs");
```

Note that `sudo` will ask for a password unless you configure it otherwise.

Another, more elegant solution, is to run a little server as `randeel` which waits for a network connection. It then runs the command and returns the output via the network connection. See the documentation for `java.net.Socket`.

Comment: hi, when i execute this command"sudo -l -U randeel /usr/bin/wine cmd /c some.vbs" i get the output as text "/usr/bin/wine cmd /c some.vbs" any solution to that? programme didn't run. i changed the sudoers to ask for no passwd.

Comment: Try it from the command line first until you get the output you want. Only when that works, try to get the Java code to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions.
1. give appropriate execute permissions to wine using chmod a+x. 
2. If you do not want to do #1 you have to run command line that first changes the user and then runs the application.
command su USERNAME
changes current user but requires typing password. To emulate the terminal that types password you can use expect script.

Then you can run command as different user. If you are going to use this way I'd recommend you to write short shell script that does these 2 actions and run this script from java.

The #2 is more complicated. Way #1 seems to be much simpler.